# Раскрывающиеся меню всегда открыто

Tags: javascript, html, css, opencart

Друзья, подскажите http://lxxnutsxsmu46.bitte14.in.ua/test2/
вот слева меню, когда жмешь на подпункт оно сворачивается - подскажите как сделать что бы оно открыто было при активном элементе меню

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

После загрузки страницы ищите элементы по классу "subcart", но без "collapsed", вызываете программно клик по нему. Это лучшее, что могу посоветовать без кода.